# ANDROID - button redirect to browser and download php generated pdf

Tags: php, android, pdf, fpdf, android-download-manager

I am currently developing a mobile application that serves as a mobile companion app of our web application. Which is a class record system. Using fpdf I can generated pdf of class records by going to that php file and with URL variables and getting those variables by `$_GET[''];`

My problem is I have no idea how to execute it in Android. I am using volley for network requests.

In the link I can just do..

`int ID = 120120;`

`String URL = "http://www.domain.xyz/printrecords.php?classid="+ID+"";`

But how do I do so that when I access that link I get redirected to the browser and automatically download the pdf.

I am just new in android and have not yet encountered the need for this so I do not know what do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it will open browser with specific url and if your browser has inbuilt functionality it will open pdf in browser otherwise it will download.

```
int ID = 120120;
Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://www.domain.xyz/printrecords.php?classid="+ID));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```